# SSRS AVG function with where clause

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder, reporting-services-2012

I have a question about the avg-function in SSRS/Report Builder. What I want to achieve is a expression which is giving a average of the lead time per incident which is taking the urgency of the incident in account. I already made this simple expression for all the incidents which works fine: `=Avg(Fields!Lead_time_call__in_days_.Value, "DataSet1")`

This is the expression I made which should take the urgency in account (but which doesn't work): `=AVG(IIF(Fields!Urgency.Value = "Low", Fields!Lead_time_call__in_days_.Value, 0), "DataSet1")`

This displays this: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVich.png)
But that's not possible, since the individual averages can't be all lower than the total average (which is correct)

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: What isn't working about what you have tried so far?

Comment: It displays a number, but that number is not correct. I also don't understand where the number comes from. For instance it displays 2 while it has to be 8. I know it has to be 8 because I can calculate it myself from the results from the dataset.

Comment: I think it doesn't calculate the right averages because of the ',0' part. If the number isn't 'Low', it inserts a 0 and that messes up the average. But how can I solve it?

Comment: The `0` would be what is used if the urgency isn't low. You should replace the `0` with however you want lead time to be calculated for your other urgency types.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! Thanks to @xcvd for helping. I just had to replace the `0` with `nothing`. That acts as a `NULL` and doesn't messes up the calculation.